# How to save the outcome of collection.find into Array

Tags: mongodb, scala

```
object ConnHelper extends Serializable{
  lazy val jedis = new Jedis("localhost")
  lazy val mongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/recommender")
}
val ratingCollection = ConnHelper.mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoConfig.db).getCollection(MONGODB_RATING_COLLECTION)
val Existratings: Observable[Option[BsonValue]] = ratingCollection
    .find(equal("userId",1234))
    .map{
    item => item.get("productId")
    }
```

The documents are like these

```
{
  "id":****,
  "userId":4567,
  "productId":12345,
  "score":5.0
}
```

I use Scala and Mongo-Scala-driver 2.9.0 to connect MongoDB and find documents where the "userId" field equal 1234, then I want save the value of "productId" of the documents into Array, but the returned value is observable type.
Could anyone tell how to save the query outcome into Array? I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mongo Scala Driver uses the Observable [model](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) which is composed by three parts.

You need to subscribe an observer to the observable. Take a look to the [examples](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/reference/observables/).

The fastest solution is to coplete with a toFuture call:

```
val Existratings =
      ratingCollection
      .find(equal("userId",1234))
      .map{
        item => item.get("productId")
      }.toFuture()
```

That will return a Sep of BsonValues with the resultset

Comment: yeah, it works after i add `Await.result(ratingExists, Duration.Inf).toArray`

Comment: Note that most of the Scala libraries works in an async fashion. The most common is to connect these apis that work with Futures and can be directly connected with other frameworks like Akka.

Answer (score 1):

Please try a method which uses a *Promise/Future* structure to find the sequence of documents that match the search criteria. For example:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.bson._
```

```
def find (search_key: String, search_value: String, collection_name: String): Seq[Document] = {

    // The application will need to wait for the find operation thread to complete
    // in order to process the returned value.

    log.debug(s"Starting database find_all operation thread")

    // Set up new client connection, database, and collection
    val _client: MongoClient = MongoClient(config_client)
    val _database: MongoDatabase = _client.getDatabase(config_database)
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = _database.getCollection(collection_name)

    // Set up result sequence
    var result_seq : Seq[Document] = Seq.empty

    // Set up Promise container to wait for the database operation to complete
    val promise = Promise[Boolean]

    // Start insert operation thread; once the thread has finished, read resulting documents.
    collection.find(equal(search_key, search_value)).collect().subscribe((results: Seq[Document]) => {
      log.trace(s"Found operation thread completed")
      // Append found documents to the results
      result_seq = result_seq ++ results
      log.trace(s" Result sequence: $result_seq")

      promise.success(true) // set Promise container
      _client.close // close client connection to avoid memory leaks
     })


    val future = promise.future // Promise completion result
    Await.result(future, Duration.Inf) // wait for the promise completion result

    // Return document sequence
    result_seq

  }
```

Then you can iterate through the document sequence and pull the products into a List (better than Array).

```
def read : List[String] = {

    val document_seq = Database.find("userID","1234",collection)

    // Set up an empty return map
    val return_map : mutable.Map[String, String] = mutable.Map.empty

    // Translate data from each document into Product object
    document_seq.foreach(_document => {
      return_map.put(
         _document("id").asString.getValue,
         _document("productId").asString.getValue
        )
      
    })

    // Convert values to list map and return
    return_map.values.toList
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! You posted an answer promoting your repository/blog/product. That can be considered spam. Please see: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212), [Some tips and advice about self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/), and [What makes something spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/356669).

Comment: You should [explain why and how it solves the problem, and provide code on how to use it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605), along with disclosing that it's your library. All of which should be in the answer itself. ***You did all the above, except disclosing your affiliation.***

Answer (score 0):

this maybe:

```
val productIds = ratingCollection
    .find(equal("userId",1234))
    .map { _.get("productId") }
    .toArray
```

Comment: thank you for replying, but it doesn't work, there is no **toArray** method

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution to get an Array is to fold directly in one:

```scala
      ratingCollection
        .find(???)
        .map { ??? }
        .foldLeft(Array.empty[Item]) { _ :+ _ }
        .head() //in order to get a Future[Array[Item]]
        .onComplete {
          case Success(values: Array[Item]) => //capture the array
          case Failure(exception) => //fail logic
        }
```

It's probably best to work with the Future rather build your own Observer logic for subscription.